# How do I change OnClick to addEventListener in the example below?

Tags: javascript, html, events

The goal here is to completely get rid of OnClick in HTML and execute everything in JS instead, preferably by using `addEventListener`.

```js
function ShowImage(imgs) {
  var expandedImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
  expandedImg.src = imgs.src;
  expandedImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.field {
  padding: 3px 3px;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

.expandedImg {
  width: 75%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.containerimage {
  position: relative;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerimage">
  <!-- Expanded image -->
  <img id="expandedImg">
</div>

<div class="field">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp5539369.jpg" onclick="ShowImage(this);"> </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp5441501.jpg" onclick="ShowImage(this);">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp5405231.jpg" onclick="ShowImage(this);"> </div>
</div>

<div class="field">
  <div class="gallery">
    <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp4964086.png" onclick="ShowImage(this);"> </div>
</div>
```

Afterwards, I tried adding the following code in JS,

```js
var galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery img");
for (var image of galleryImages) {
  image.addEventListener('click', ShowImage);
}
```

However, this only makes the clicked image appear for a split second and disappear, showing only the image icon instead.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

To use `addEventListener` instead of `onClick` in the `img` tags, you can remove the `onclick` attributes from the HTML code and use `addEventListener` to attach a click event to each image in your JavaScript code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gallery</title>
    <style>
        div.gallery img {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
        }
        .field{
            padding: 3px 3px;
            float: left;
            width:20%;
        }
        .expandedImg{
            width: 75%;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }
        .containerimage {
            position: relative; 
            display: none;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="containerimage">
        <!-- Expanded image -->
        <img id="expandedImg">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp5539369.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp5441501.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp5405231.jpg">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
        <div class="gallery">
            <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp4964086.png">
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        function ShowImage(event) {
            var expandedImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
            expandedImg.src = event.target.src;
            expandedImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
        }

        var galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery img");
        for (var i = 0; i < galleryImages.length; i++) {
            galleryImages[i].addEventListener("click", ShowImage);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If i have undrestood your code correctly you just need to use `document.querySelectorAll(.class)` and then loop through them with `document.addEventListener('click', 'your function()')`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @mihail nicoara

I've done this snippet just after your edit, so this is perhaps a cross post.

```js
        function ShowImage(imgs) {
          var expandedImg = document.getElementById("expandedImg");
          expandedImg.src = this.getAttribute("src");
          expandedImg.parentElement.style.display = "block";
        }
        var galleryImages = document.querySelectorAll(".gallery img");
        for (var image of galleryImages) {
          image.addEventListener('click', ShowImage);
        }
```

```css
        div.gallery img {
          width: 100%;
          height: auto;
        }

        .field {
          padding: 3px 3px;
          float: left;
          width: 20%;
        }

        .expandedImg {
          width: 75%;
          margin: 0 auto;
        }

        .containerimage {
          position: relative;
          display: none;
          text-align: center;
        }
```

```html
    <div class="containerimage">
      <!-- Expanded image -->
      <img id="expandedImg" alt="img">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="gallery">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp5539369.jpg" alt="img"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="gallery">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp5441501.jpg" alt="img">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="gallery">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp5405231.jpg" alt="img"> </div>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <div class="gallery">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp1x/wp4964086.png" alt="img"> </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I couldn't understand too much from you code. But I hope It will help you and Next time please try to ask question with clean code.

```js
const expandingImg = document.querySelector("any_css_selector_to_select_img");

expandingImg.addEventListener("click", (e) => 
    /* Write your function code here */
    /* use e.target to get the current targeting Element (In this case It is expandingImg) */
})
```

Comment: My apologies, this is my first time posting on this site and the code formatting rules are acting weird from my end. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score -1):

Remove onclick attribute from tags and use this
El =Document.getElementsById("id name")
And
El.addEventListener("onclick", put your entire function here)

Comment: That is an utterly unclean code that does not scale at all. Also not really good coding to add an event lister to every single image by its id. An event delegation is needed.